# Laravel Auth login return specific error

Tags: laravel

this is me code

```
public function login_Post()
{
    if (Auth::user()->attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'), 'active' => 1)))
    {
        Event::fire('users.login');
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'succsed');
    }
    else
        return Redirect::to('user/login')->withInput(Input::except('password'));
}
```

i want warn user when he/she is not active to active how i can undrestand the activation require or login failed by wrong user name or password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way with the code you already have is to `Auth::attempt()` first, then check the `active` property so you can return a separate error.

**Controller:**

```
public function login_Post()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'))))
    {

        if(!Auth::user()->active)
        {
            Auth::logout();
            return Redirect::to('user/login')->with('errors', ['Your account hasn't been activated']);

        }

        Event::fire('users.login');
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'succsed');
    }
    else
        return Redirect::to('user/login')->withInput(Input::except('password'))->with('errors', ['Authentication failed.']);;
}
```

**Then in an errors view:**

```
@if( Session::get('errors') )

    <ul class="error">
        @foreach( Session::get('errors') as $message )
            @if(is_array($message))
                @foreach( $message as $subMessage )
                    <li>{{ $subMessage }}</li>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <li>{{ $message }}</li>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </ul>

@endif
```

Comment: this is nice but,.. how to get the specific error? instead i using for each?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check if the user exists first:

```
if ( ! User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->first())
{
   return 'This user does not exists';
}
```

Then attempt:

```
Auth::user()->attempt(...);
```